# Windows turning webcam off after reload of page

Tags: windows, usb, javascript, webcam

I am currently running a Booking System on a HTML page that is always reading the webcam. But after random times of reloading the page, the webcam fails to load with the error `NotReadableError: Could not start video source` - Once I re-plug the webcam into the USB port, it starts working, until the issue occurs again.

The webcam reader script is called Instascan. I have tried to use a different reader script, but the same type of thing happens.

Does Windows disconnect the Webcam after certain amounts of time - and is there a way to fix it?

Edit: I have also tried to disable the 'USB Selective Suspend Setting', but this also makes no difference.

Another Edit: After checking event viewer, I find this error at every time the webcam stops working

> The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local
>   Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID {some
>   id} and APPIP {some id} to the user NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE SID
>   (S-I-5-19) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running the application
>   container Unavailable SID (Unavailable).

Comment: After the webcam has failed, you should check with Device Manager whether the device is still present. Also check with Event Viewer for any errors.

Comment: The device still exists in device manager, I can reboot the USB port using devcon and it will temporarily fix the issue.

Comment: The event viewer showed a long error, i've edited my answer with it.

Comment: That’s probably unrelated. I’d still guess the webcam’s driver is to blame.